# Is there a service I can use and setup on my website to handle user's payments?

Tags: webapp-rec

I have a website and want to let users pay monthly fees to get the service and in some cases will pay once per transaction.

Is there a simple service I can integrate in my website to handle this and allow users to pay using different ways, such as PayPal, VISA, .... ?

Note: I don't have a PayPal account and it is not possible to have one here in my country. It will be nice if payments can transfer to my bank account.

Comment: This might be better asked at the [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: This question might have different solutions depending on your Country. Could you please specify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Plimus](http://plimus.com) - I have heard good things about them.

Other good options are Shareit or RegNow.